# Getting LDAP account from iOS device

Tags: ios, ldap

I already posted on the apple dev forum but it seems nobody wants to answer, considering that I posted it on the general forum instead of the IOS dev one, so I'm hoping to get answers here.

Hello. First of all, I'm a newbie at iOS dev and my employer asked me to update his app that is already available on the store. Among the updates was the LDAP imports. After finishing all the other updates, I spent 2 days trying to figure out how to use LDAP on xcode and I'm able to get the connecting and searching part working.

My main question is, how would I get the LDAP account info from the device so that I dont have to make a pop up screen, asking for the ldap account. in the app. I believe this is possible since I've seen most apps access facebook and twitter account so why not LDAP? If theres nothing, could you tell me how to access the other accounts, like mail, facebook or twitter account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mehh. On second thought, just forget about it. I'll just create my own LDAP account setting on my app. I already ton a lot of research and I found out that I can't get access to a list of emails registered on the device cause of security reasons. Unless someone has a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Some one is storing the connect information for "the other accounts, like mail, facebook or twitter account."

You need to pop-up but should be able to store the previous credentials in the app somewhere.

We did this using the http://xamarin.com/studio

-jim

Comment: is this useful to what im after? cause all I see is an alternative IDE from xcode, which is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Some one is storing the connect information for "the other accounts, like mail, facebook or twitter account."

Comment: errr ok... you're telling me to do something like searching a needle on the haystack, where I have to search a 1-2 lines of code in a very big IDE